# @Transactional and Connection Leakage Spring Hibernate c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0, spring-transactions

In my application, i'm using

1. c3p0 as DataSource, which is passed to Hibernate session factory
2. transactionManager as HibernateTransactionManager
3. applicationConfig has tx:annotation-driven to detect @Transactional present in Service Methods and NOT in DAO methods.
4. ServiceImpl classes implement Service interface.
5. Service Methods call DAO methods.
6. DAO classes are Autowired in the ServiceImpl classes.
7. I have a DefaultDAOImpl to have common dao methods.
8. Other DAOImpl classes extend DefaultDAOImpl.
9. Service methods make single DAO call.
10. DAO methods make internal calls also, sometimes on the same DAOImpl and also on DefaultDAOImpl methods.
11. session is obtained using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession in DefaultDAOImpl as well as other DAOImpl methods.
12. session.close is NOT called from code.

Is there anything I am doing that might cause connection leak?
I am seeing c3p0 DeadLockDetector running from the logs.

Comment: did you set `hibernate.c3p0.max_size` property?

Comment: I'm using c3p0 properties  in the datasource which is configured as a bean to let spring manage the datasource. Max_statements is probably set which I'll set to 0 and see the outcome. But I'd like to know if the approach described above has any connection leakage pitfalls.

Comment: your approach seems pretty good.. but leakage also depends on the properties you are setting.. just make sure they are correct. BTW, `hibernate.c3p0.max_size` is limit the open connection pools

Comment: The DeadlockDetector says [Finished. No pending tasks]. But it is running for every database query.